# Launch TeamViewer 12 on Ubuntu 16 before login

Tags: ubuntu, teamviewer

When I have logged into my machine and it fires the login-screen, I can access and use it to re-enter my password in the TeamViewer session window.

The problem is that, when the machine has just booted up, it doesn't register for TeamViewer hence I can't connect to it. Is there a way to launch TeamViewer in a way that I can get past the login screen remotely?

Like, the login screen itself works once I've logged into the system before. But after rebooting, TeamViewer shows the machine as being offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the internet connection wasn't being established before logging in to the device.

Allowing all users (including the login screen) to access the internet did the trick.
[image]

Comment: This is enabled but still not working for me in linux mint 18.3 with teamviewer 12